# Building a game in Unity with Python OpenCV and MediaPipe

Tags: unity, python, build-process, build

In Python, I have OpenCV and MediaPipe for the hand tracking controls for the Unity, and I want to build the game without opening the PyCharm to read the hand. Is there any way to build the project with the Python OpenCV and MediaPipe?

Comment: Since there is https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/opencv-plus-unity-85928 and https://github.com/homuler/MediaPipeUnityPlugin after a quick google search, it should be possible to use both.